# 1980s children's storybook about a boy's journey from Earth to Mars

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, mars

I’m looking for a children's storybook from the '80s about a boy who moves from Earth to Mars. The book came with a cassette with the boy narrating. I recall the intro man's voice saying, "this has been recorded in quadraphonic stereo, so wear headphones for best experience," or something like that. Would love to find title.

Comment: [Young Visitor to Mars?](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4483792.Young_Visitor_to_Mars)